# Not having all the errors captured in Sentry SDK in Jitsi meet web project

Tags: reactjs, sentry, error-logging, jitsi, jitsi-meet

We have jitsi meet hosted in our own server, and we want to capture errors in client browser side in Sentry.

I have added Sentry initialization in Jitsi meet project in react/index.web.js file

[image]

After deploy and run, I can get the error log in Sentry Dashboard, but there are not too many transactions and errors to be expected. Like I can see errors in the Browser console that is logging, but many of those errors are not present in Sentry.

Does Sentry not send all the errors to SDK? Do I need to send try catch error manually to Sentry or sentry SDK handles those? Please any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.